# If I only have the main repository enabled will it cause dependency problems with universe, restricted and multiverse?

Tags: software-center, package-management

I have a questiong regarding installation of packages using Software Center.

If I choose only main repository and istall a package could I get problems if the package has dependency to another package which is not in the main repository?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "main repository" ?

Comment: I mean I would like to avoid intallation from universe multiverse and restricted repositories. But do not know if I just select software from main (in the software center source selection windows) could it cause any problems?

Answer (score 1):

Software in `main` cannot have runtime dependencies on software in `universe` or `multiverse`. However, the bulk of available software is in `universe`, so if you want to install additional software, it is very likely something you want to install is located there, rather than in `main`.

And once the archive re-org is completed, there will be no separation between `main` and `universe` in this way. They will be the same archive, and some packages will be flagged as `supported` and such, instead.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. I just want to install texlive-fonts-extra which is in the main repository but has some suggested packages form universe. I just unchecked all the boxes except main: under Software Center -> software sources -> ubuntu software. Would if work like this?

Comment: Sorry for the double comment but what I mean is - in the "software sources" are also certain default settings on the "other software", e. g. independent (source code) is checked. Would it be possible when installing the package and it needs a package from universe (that is not availabe since I unchecked the box) is downloads something bad from  "independent (source code)"?

Comment: `Suggested` packages are just that, suggested. They are not installed when you install the thing that suggests them. You have to manually select to install them as well. They are only suggestions, not requirements. However, that package is in universe, not main (at least, in 13.10 it is).

Comment: That means, if I again check all the boxes in the software sources and then install the packages from "main" everithing would be secure? How can I tell it comes from main? In the software center I discoverd that it is possible to "view" -> Canonical-Mantained-Software. If I chose this option will it show me only the applications in main?

Comment: `apt-cache policy $packagename` will show you where `$packagename` is available from, and where the installation candidate would come from.

Comment: sorry for stupid question... but I do not know where to check it in the software center? There are no package names only program names..

Comment: That specificity of information is not visible in the software-center app. You need to open a terminal and use the apt commands to see it all.