# A package is there with a dependency missing: bug or misunderstanding?

Tags: 16.04, package-management, xorg, dpkg, dependencies

### Background

I just installed Ubuntu Xenial on a partition, after a long time running Ubuntu Trusty. I started a script (of mine) to check what's new and what's out in the installed packages, when this script stopped with an error complaining `xorg` depends on `xserver-xorg` which was not found and neither provided by another package.

I checked indeed, this dependency is stated and it is not fulfilled. The same package exists in Ubuntu Trusty, with that same dependency (among others), and this dependency is fulfilled.

### Question

Are there any case where it’s OK for a package to be there with one of more dependencies missing? Or is this a bug? (was after the fresh installation with updates executed during install). Or is this me who need to learn something about packages dependencies?

Comment: What version of ubuntu and what repositories do you have enabled ? Yes this can happen if you do not have the proper repositories enabled.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen, this is Ubuntu 16.04, and the installation ISO image was 16.04.3. The repositories are servers in France (according to Synaptic). I noticed installing the missing dependency would requires to remove some actually installed packages (all related to X). As an hypothesis, I was wondering if this package is a special case.

Comment: No dependencies and conflicts come and go. You would need to post the details. Usually you will get an error package not found. Tons of examples. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/689935/unable-to-locate-package-mingw32/689972#689972 and https://askubuntu.com/questions/350822/if-i-only-have-the-main-repository-enabled-will-it-cause-dependency-problems-wit